# VOC Monitor "Input Not Support" on GRUB

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, grub2

When I boot my PC with both Windows and Ubuntu installed: I always get the exact message "Input not Support" without the -ed flashing on my VOC monitor. GRUB does not show so I can't reach Windows. I have tried blindly pressing the "down" key and "Enter" but it yields no response. I have an NVidia card with the extra 3D graphics driver applied also.

additional comment:
Same here. sshd is running, I can log into the system remotely from another PC, everything is working fine; just I can't see anything on the monitor that is directly attached.
I guess somewhere within grub configuration there must be something to set the video output resolution, but where ???

Answer (score 0):

*An anonymous user (possibly the original poster while not logged in, or possibly someone else, there is no way to know) proposed the following solution as an edit. I've made it into an answer instead (with slight formatting changes):*

I found the solution (if you are able to login, e.g., via ssh):

Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot.